# Adding Labels to lines in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

So I am not very deep into my learning of R or ggplot, but I am in a class that is doing some coding. For one of my projects, I am trying to go a little above and beyond by putting labels on some of the lines, but I'm not sure how to do that.

This is my code:

```
downpp_median <- median(songs$download_pp)
#Create quartile variables
downpp_qone <- quantile(songs$download_pp, 1/4)
downpp_qthree <- quantile(songs$download_pp, 3/4)
  
#Create Violin Plot
ggplot(songs, aes(x = condition, y = download_pp, fill = condition)) + 
  geom_violin(alpha = .3) + 
#Add log scale on the y-axis
  scale_y_log10() +
#Add median line
  geom_hline(yintercept = downpp_median, color = "orange") +
#Add quartile lines
  geom_hline(yintercept = downpp_qone, color = "purple") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = downpp_qthree, color = "purple") +
#Add labels
  labs(title = "Average # of Downloads Per User 
       Against Condition",
       x = "Condition",
       y = "Downloads",
       fill = "Conditions")
```

I am trying to add labels on the median and quartile lines, but I'm not sure how to do that. If anyone has any tips, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `annotate("text", ....)` is a good way to add labels. Another way is to make a summary table with the locations and labels you want, and to use `geom_text(data = SUMMARY_TABLE, ...)` to refer to it.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0):

You can add these use the `annotate` geom. You can provide it the x and y of where the label will go in the call. Example below:

```
#fake data to test
songs <- data.frame(download_pp = rnorm(100,100,20),
                    condition = rep(LETTERS[1:5], each = 20))

downpp_median <- median(songs$download_pp)
#Create quartile variables
downpp_qone <- quantile(songs$download_pp, 1/4)
downpp_qthree <- quantile(songs$download_pp, 3/4)

#Create Violin Plot
ggplot(songs, aes(x = condition, y = download_pp, fill = condition)) + 
  geom_violin(alpha = .3) + 
  #Add log scale on the y-axis
  scale_y_log10() +
  #Add median line
  geom_hline(yintercept = downpp_median, color = "orange") +
  #Add quartile lines
  geom_hline(yintercept = downpp_qone, color = "purple") +
  geom_hline(yintercept = downpp_qthree, color = "purple") +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = "E", y = downpp_median, label = "Median") +
  annotate(geom = "label", x = 3, y = downpp_qone, label = "1st Quartile") +
  #Add labels
  labs(title = "Average # of Downloads Per User 
       Against Condition",
       x = "Condition",
       y = "Downloads",
       fill = "Conditions")
```

It is a little complicated because you are using the `condition` for the fill, which means the x-axis corresponds to the different categories. So you can use the name of the category where you want it placed (where I put E in the code) or a number (remembering that each category is an increase of 1 along the x-axis). You can also specify different geom's. `geom="text"` will add just text while `geom="label"` will add text in a box.

Here's what the code above creates:

[image]